# append a string to a number field in Pentaho Report Designer

Tags: pentaho

I have a number field which is the output of a query in the Report Designer and what I would like to do is append "AM - [number+1] AM/PM" to this. For eg. the query outputs 9,10,11,12,13 and so on. But, instead of the number 9 I would like to format the output as 9AM - 10AM, instead of 10, 10AM -11AM,instead of 11, 11AM - 12PM and so on. I have added a formula in the data-format part of the number field with an IF condition to check the value of the number and output it accordingly, but it doesn't work the way I want it to.

Please can someone help me out with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Value Mapper Transform, you would need an entry for each hour. Or you could use a couple of User Defied Java Expression to generate rows with (n)AM/PM and (n+1)AM.PM, and then a Concat Fields step to join them.